# Firebase Storage Security Rule (Image dimensions)

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am running a problem with my app. I want to check in the backend if the photo which has been uploaded has the allowed dimensions (1024px * 1024px or 1024px * 1980 px, for example), and also that the image is lower than 30MB (for all dimensions).

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /photos/{photo} {
      function hasValidSize() {
        // Max. photo size = 30MB (For all dimensions)
        return request.resource.size < 30 * 1024 * 1024;
      }
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && hasValidSize();
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to check the photo dimensions as a security rule too?

Pd: I have already implemented a photo cropper that has 3 possible dimensions, but what if a hacker downloads the client code and modifies it?...

Thanks.

Comment: Should I use https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/storage-resize-images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to check image dimensions in security rules.  The only thing you can check is the total size of the file, which is what `request.resource.size` is used for.

In fact, Cloud Storage is used for any type of content at all.  It's not limited to images, and doesn't have any special considerations for images.  To Cloud Storage, everything is just a sequence of bytes.

If you need to place limits on the contents of the file, you'll need to write some backend code for that, and make sure all your clients are using that backend for the upload.  Either that, or use Cloud Functions to write a trigger that deletes invalid files after they've been uploaded.

Comment: And do you know how to get the image dimensions from the storage?

Comment: You can use an image processing library to find that out.

Comment: At the end I have added custom metadata (width and height (and the userId too to send an email to those who attempts to break the app security)) to the images. I know that's not the best solution but working. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Be aware that clients can choose whatever metadata that they add.  It doesn't have to match the contents of the object.

Comment: @DougStevenson my plan is just to have a cloud function hook onto writes into cloud storage (only restricting max file size), download the item into the cloud function runtime, and do various things such as calculating minimum DPI and such. All this should be done client side, but I'll have a restricted metadata field for the cloud storage object that will be used by the cloud function to mark the object as being verified correct dimensions and such. Is that a reasonable pattern, or would you recommend something different?

Comment: I figure for the happy path of non-malicious users, all their uploads will get verified assuming my frontend verification (before upload) and backend verification (in the cloud function reacting to upload) is identical